# Issue on converting EnrichedActivity to String

Tags: getstream-io

I need to convert EnrichedActivity to String as I use stream-java:3.2.4 in a Flutter application.

I get EnrichedActivity list like this:

```
 val list : List<EnrichedActivity> =   client.flatFeed("user").getEnrichedActivities(EnrichmentFlags()
             .withOwnReactions()
             .withRecentReactions()
             .withReactionCounts()).get()
```

Then I try to convert the list like this:

```
val resultString = ObjectMapper()
                        .setSerializationInclusion(com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)
                        .writeValueAsString(list)
```

But some fields are erased by FasterXml-jackson (v2.9.6).

**Isn't this the correct way to convert an EnrichedActivity list to String?**

**Note 1- Original EnrichedActivity list:**

> 0 = {EnrichedActivity@15673}
> "EnrichedActivity{id=5e02d656-27ef-11eb-88f9-128a130028af,
> actor=Data{id=RqO5ns7mrYfvain3ETQpdPgIQZz1,
> data={updated_at=2020-11-11T22:46:38.568116Z,
> name=RqO5ns7mrYfvain3ETQpdPgIQZz1,
> created_at=2020-11-11T22:46:38.568116Z}}, verb=post,
> object=Data{id=b0e249e9-8695-4161-bb24-d3980da4cdeb, data={}},
> foreignID=, target=Data{id=, data={}}, time=Mon Nov 16 12:37:39
> GMT+03:00 2020, origin=null, to=null, score=null,
> ownReactions={like=[Reaction{id=4186ea14-f3e5-4368-8a91-eafc12e3045b,
> appID=null, kind=like, userID=RqO5ns7mrYfvain3ETQpdPgIQZz1,
> activityID=5e02d656-27ef-11eb-88f9-128a130028af, parent=,
> ownChildren=null, latestChildren={}, childrenCounts={},
> userData=Data{id=RqO5ns7mrYfvain3ETQpdPgIQZz1,
> data={updated_at=2020-11-11T22:46:38.568116Z,
> name=RqO5ns7mrYfvain3ETQpdPgIQZz1,
> created_at=2020-11-11T22:46:38.568116Z}}, activityData={},
> extra={updated_at=2020-11-16T09:39:25.088760Z,
> created_at=2020-11-16T09:39:25.088760Z}}]},
> latestReactions={like=[Reaction{id=4186ea14-f3e5-4368-8a91-eafc12"

> 1= {EnrichedActivity@15674}
> "EnrichedActivity{id=6f18988b-277d-11eb-96e2-1254437355c5,
> actor=Data{id=RqO5ns7mrYfvain3ETQpdPgIQZz1,
> data={updated_at=2020-11-11T22:46:38.568116Z,
> name=RqO5ns7mrYfvain3ETQpdPgIQZz1,
> created_at=2020-11-11T22:46:38.568116Z}}, verb=post,
> object=Data{id=11f22b84-5168-452e-b098-c9f60818d6b2, data={}},
> foreignID=, target=Data{id=, data={}}, time=Sun Nov 15 23:02:05
> GMT+03:00 2020, origin=null, to=null, score=null,
> ownReactions={like=[Reaction{id=63471022-3e44-4d44-ad3d-6104d96a0843,
> appID=null, kind=like, userID=RqO5ns7mrYfvain3ETQpdPgIQZz1,
> activityID=6f18988b-277d-11eb-96e2-1254437355c5, parent=,
> ownChildren=null, latestChildren={}, childrenCounts={},
> userData=Data{id=RqO5ns7mrYfvain3ETQpdPgIQZz1,
> data={updated_at=2020-11-11T22:46:38.568116Z,
> name=RqO5ns7mrYfvain3ETQpdPgIQZz1,
> created_at=2020-11-11T22:46:38.568116Z}}, activityData={},
> extra={updated_at=2020-11-16T09:31:16.925141Z,
> created_at=2020-11-16T09:31:16.925141Z}},
> Reaction{id=9c7e0401-6ed0-47a8-b239-2669786e3340, appID=null, kind="

**Note 2- The serialized form of the list above:**

> [ { "actor": { "id": "RqO5ns7mrYfvain3ETQpdPgIQZz1", "updated_at":
> "2020-11-11T22:46:38.568116Z", "name": "RqO5ns7mrYfvain3ETQpdPgIQZz1",
> "created_at": "2020-11-11T22:46:38.568116Z" }, "id":
> "5e02d656-27ef-11eb-88f9-128a130028af", "object": { "id":
> "b0e249e9-8695-4161-bb24-d3980da4cdeb" }, "target": { "id": "" },
> "time": "2020-11-16T09:37:39.284", "verb": "post", "foreign_id": "",
> "message": "test2", "latest_reactions_extra": { "like": { "next": "" }
> } }, { "actor": { "id": "RqO5ns7mrYfvain3ETQpdPgIQZz1", "updated_at":
> "2020-11-11T22:46:38.568116Z", "name": "RqO5ns7mrYfvain3ETQpdPgIQZz1",
> "created_at": "2020-11-11T22:46:38.568116Z" }, "id":
> "6f18988b-277d-11eb-96e2-1254437355c5", "object": { "id":
> "11f22b84-5168-452e-b098-c9f60818d6b2" }, "target": { "id": "" },
> "time": "2020-11-15T20:02:05.321", "verb": "post", "foreign_id": "",
> "message": "Test", "latest_reactions_extra": { "like": { "next":
> "https://stream-io-api.com/api/v1.0/reaction/activity_id/6f18988b-277d-11eb-96e2-1254437355c5/like/?id_lt=4fa212db-0125-4b4e-9a77-04e4940ec64a&limit=5&withOwnChildren=false"
> } } } ]